# How to print std::chrono types with google test?

Tags: c++, googletest

I'm trying to use `std::chrono` types with google test. My first approach is to define `PrintTo` for `nanoseconds` in namespace `std::chrono`, but unfortunately [it is undefined behavior to add declarations or definitions to namespace `std` or to any namespace nested within `std`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std). The following code demonstrates the idea.

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <chrono>

namespace std::chrono {

void PrintTo(nanoseconds ns, std::ostream* os) // UB
{
    *os << ns.count() << " nanoseconds ";
}

}

namespace {

struct MyTest : ::testing::Test{
};

TEST_F(MyTest, PrintingTest)
{
    using namespace testing;
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    ASSERT_THAT(1ns, Eq(2ns));
}

}
```

If `std::chrono::PrintTo` is defined, it prints:

```
Value of: 1ns
Expected: is equal to 2 nanoseconds 
  Actual:
```

If `std::chrono::PrintTo` is not defined, it prints via default byte printer:

```
Value of: 1ns
Expected: is equal to 8-byte object <02-00 00-00 00-00 00-00>
  Actual:
```

What is the idiomatic way to define a printer for `std::chrono` types with google test?

Comment: [C++20's `operator<<()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/operator_ltlt) will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can overload the std::ostream operator for the chrono types as follow:

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <chrono>

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const ::std::chrono::nanoseconds& ns) 
{
  return os << ns.count() << " nanoseconds ";
}

namespace {

struct MyTest : ::testing::Test{
};

TEST_F(MyTest, PrintingTest)
{
    using namespace testing;
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    ASSERT_EQ(1ns, 2ns);
}

}
```

The output should then be as expected:

```
error:       Expected: 1ns
      Which is: 1 nanoseconds
To be equal to: 2ns
      Which is: 2 nanoseconds
[  FAILED  ] MyTest.PrintingTest (0 ms)
```

Comment: Btw, this is going to cause ODR violations (because of the default printer in google test's `UniversalPrinter`) if there's another cpp file that doesn't define `operator<<(... std::chrono::nanoseconds)` of defines it differently.

Comment: @DevNull True, but then your options are "undefined behavior" vs "possible ODR", I don't know if there is another proper way. I use the UB (as in your question) implementation in my tests, I think for this case it is acceptable and *properly defined* for the current STL, it might become UB in future. Perhaps a question on the gtest github page should be place to try and ask the developers what they recommend

Comment: The problem with UB is that it can work, but it might not... I'm having two targets, one with gcc (7.5) and one with clang (8.0.1). This solution works fine for the first one, but fails to work for the latter.

Comment: @Quarra You might need to move the implementation into the std::chrono namespace in the same way that the original question does with PrintTo(). If that works for both then it would be good to know which one is correct and which one is wrong with the given solution.

Comment: But isn't extending of std namespace a UB in itself? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std